# Set of matrices closed under multiplication: necessary conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a finite set of square matrices $M_1,\ldots,M_n$ of the same dimensions, are there conditions that would guarantee that a multiplication of any two matrices from the set results in a matrix from the set up to a scalar multiplication?

Comment: One way to generate such a set is to consider $\{I,A,A^2,A^3,\dots\}$ for some $n \times n$ matrix $A$. By the Cayley Hamilton theorem, this set will always be finite with size at most $n$.

Comment: Another interesting example of such a set is the [Pauli Matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices)

Answer (score 0):

One such condition is for matrices to be powers of the adjacency matrix of a directed n-cycle.

For example for the cycle $$v_1\to v_2\to v_3\to v_1$$ we get $$M_1=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1& 0\\0 & 0 & 1\\1 & 0 & 0\\ \end{bmatrix}$$
$$M_2=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0& 1\\1& 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\\ \end{bmatrix}$$
$$M_3=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0& 0\\0& 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\\ \end{bmatrix}$$